# No property desc found for type Instant! in Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a SpringBoot 2.0.5.RELEASE app. in where I have an object with an Instant property:

```
private Instant dateReceived;
```

in the `CrudRepository` interface I've created this method:

```
HotelEvent findFirstbyHotelAndLatitudeNotNullAndLongitudeNotNullOrderByDateReceivedDesc(Hotel hotel);
```

But when I start the app. I got this error:

```
No property desc found for type Instant! Traversed path: HotelEvent.dateReceived.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: `findFirstby` should be `findFirstBy`